# How to read the FrameBuffer of an Android device to make system screenshot?

Tags: android, screenshot, inputstream, capture, framebuffer

I would know how to take the system screenshot (not of activity, of the entire system) of an Android device. I tried to:
using OpenGL library, but i can't find a complete code...
using a process, like this:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat /dev/graphics/fb0");
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
```

but, how should I continue after that? How can I read the image took before with cat command? I tried to do this:

```
in.read(byteArray);
```

but the method doesn't work, don't put anything in the byte array... please help me, I've hurted my brain!